# Perform closest facility analysis with Euclidean distance (without network analyst)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance

Is there anyway to use the closest facility analysis tool from Network analyst without actually having a network (streets) layer which means without using the network analyst? Because I want to find out the distances from each point to every other point based on straight line Euclidean distances.

Comment: What you are looking for is called Spider diagram or Desire lines. There are functions for this in both ArcMap, QGIS, ET Geowizards and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you explicitly state you want to find the distance and not the actual line geometry. If you have an *Advanced* level license for ArcMap you can use the [Point Distance tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm) or [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm).